# Can't Play Video from SD Card in video view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

VideoView in RelativeLayout and the code to open and play video in video view is below. by changing the backgroud color of videoview i can check the visibility of videoview but video is not being played one more thing i can hear the sound of the video but the content in the video is not shown.
Thank you.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#9057ac"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/videoContainer">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/CancelRecording"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/VideoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/UploadButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


public class CameraActivity extends Activity{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third_activity_viewpager);
    private RelativeLayout videoContainer;
    videoContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoContainer);
    videoContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String video = file.toString();
                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video));
                    videoView.start();
 //i checked the *file* path is correct no need to worry about Path.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Change video video view to textureview and use it
```

**In xml:**

```
            <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_video_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextureView
                android:id="@+id/preview_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <TextureView
                android:id="@+id/preview_video_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previre_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_play_big" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**In your actvity:**

```
    implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener        , OnClickListener, OnCompletionListener 

        private TextureView surfaceView;

private ImageView imagePlay;

        surfaceView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.preview_video_2);

        surfaceView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
                surfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);

                path = getIntent().getStringExtra("your path");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onStop() {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                super.onStop();
            }

            private void prepare(Surface surface) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture arg0, int arg1,
                                                  int arg2) {
                prepare(new Surface(arg0));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture arg0) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture arg0, int arg1,
                                                    int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture arg0) {

            }
```

Comment: well i cant give you score because i dont have much points.
i must write here that i give you -100 marks SERIOUSLY the solution was of single line that is this

videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

i need to add this before i implemented 

videoView.setOnPreparedListener

thats it...!!!

Comment: No body help you if you behave like this. I put my whole code here for your help. this means not  that its completely wrong.

Comment: look i m new in Android Development, you pasted code and it completely made me depress that i m writting code totally wrong and i thought that i was doing all useless. This made me angry when i searched Querry more Elegantly i found the solution. Your code was a bit confusing and totally changed what i m doing !!!